# Convert script from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL -4 MONTH)
```

I have this SQL in MySQL, but I cannot run it in SQL Server - How do I convert it?

Answer (score 2):

[In MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e69c50/2)

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL -4 MONTH)
```

This shall give you output as :

```
2022-12-01
```

You can write the same query in [MS SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd736/1) as :

```
DATEADD(MONTH, -4, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())))
```

This gives me the same output as :

```
2022-12-01
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple more options, both based on `start of current month - 3 months`, as opposed to `start of next month - 4 months`:

```sql
DATEADD(MONTH, -3, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))

DATEADD(MONTH, -3, CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-01') AS DATE))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wc9kWPjV)